# svmono with 'draft' causes lstlistings to produce no output

Tags: listings, sv-classes

Why does the following produce no output?

```
\documentclass[draft]{svmono}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  theorem :: GROUP_10:14
    for G being finite Group,
    p being prime (natural number) holds
      (for H being Subgroup of G st
           H is_p-group_of_prime p holds
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

(Obviously  it is easy to fix this issue by switching off 'draft'  -- but I would like to understand what is happening.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unrelated to `svmono`. Class options are `global` options so it gets passed to `listings` the `draft` option of listings suppresses file handling as far as I can see. The listings documentation says

```
draft
     The package prints no stand alone files, but shows the captions and defines
     the corresponding labels. Note that a global \documentclass-option draft
     is recognized, so you don't need to repeat it as a package option.
```

Comment: Pretty old question but... can you define a placeholder element like for figures instead of just hiding the listing? Collegue of mine lost about half an hour because nobody told him that listings are hidden in draft mode.

Comment: @HendrikWiese looking at listings source I see `\def\lst@InputListing#1{%
    \begingroup
      \lsthk@PreSet \gdef\lst@intname{#1}%
      \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\lst@set}%
      \lsthk@DisplayStyle
      \catcode\active=\active
      \lst@Init\relax \let\lst@gobble\z@
      \lst@SkipToFirst
      \lst@ifprint \def\lst@next{\input{#1}}%
             \else \let\lst@next\@empty \fi
      \lst@next
      \lst@DeInit
    \endgroup}` so putting that between `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` and change `\let\lst@next\@empty` to `\def\lst@next{\fbox{#1 not printed}}` probably does something.